# What to work on?

Tags: experimental-physics, applied-physics

(I am not exactly sure if this question is supposed to go here, but it seems like the appropriate place for it.)

Hello Scientific Community,

I am soon graduating from high school and, as everyone does, I am searching for something to study at college. I have always wanted to study straight forward physics, but recently I have been having problems finding the application (possible jobs) of a physicist. My parents are trying to push me towards mechanical engineering, but I am trying to convince them I can get a decent job studying physics. They hate the idea of having me become a teacher, so that is out of question. I know many of the members in the community have studied physics, and I would like all of you out there to please help me making a short description of your job and it`s availability. If you know of any other jobs apart from the one you are on, feel free to list them.

Thanks a lot for the help

P.S: I live in a country were not many resources are spent on scientific investigation.  If you work in some kind of job on applied physics, please answer, at least a short response.  Still make an answer if you are some kind of investigator for anyone else that reads the thread in the future.

Comment: A person who is passionate about physics, will choose it as a major without thinking of employment opportunities. Such people get a fist degree, but do not end there. Depending on the country graduate studies can take another five or more years, ending up with a doctorate. The employement will be a post doc position, and then a university academic post research assistant, research associate ,associate professor, professor i.e. teaching. Or an equivalent progress in a research institude.

Comment: Again depending on the country, stopping after the first degree one can become a highschool teacher, change into another field from computers to economics and still move in research and academic circles. I had a classmate who after the first degree in physicswent to Harvard law school and became a lawyer. Another became a biologist in graduate school. There is also always administration and executive jobs, for businesses who look out for competent people, so a business school might be a choice for a masters.